# Form auto save how to know is new or edit?

Tags: php, jquery, autosave

I want to implement the auto save form.

1. I open the new form link `new-form.php`
2. Type the title then after 10 seconds it's save to database.
3. Then I continue typing the whole form.
4. Here, what is the `key` to update the previous saved content? And I'm still on `new-form.php`

What is the logic to save new entry & update after auto save.

Let me know.

Comment: First, let us know your thoughts/approach over this. What did you have in mind? Did you even try out something? Do you have something that you want to try?

Comment: Are you a control freak? People may get interrupted or decide not to send the form. Would you like to post a form without considering it before the other person gets hold of it. Does not all of us sometime write something on a complaint form and leave it for a while to consider posting it - then decide not to as it may be unwise?

Comment: Refresh the page after first auto save and change it to `edit.php?id=1`? Or should I have a temporary table?

Comment: @EdHeal there will have draft or published status. User may delete it.

Comment: Can they just leave it on the browser and submit when done. When done it is draft and they can reopen it before choosing to publish it. So why the auto save bit?

Comment: It's a large input form. Just in case, maybe user already uploaded images & write half of form so better to have auto save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you can take a hidden field in form for ex. form_id initially it will be blank, it means it will create form.. when first time form saves it will be inserted to database. and then you return newly inserted id of the form to ajax response on ajax success you can set the hidden field value to newly created form id and now if id of form is passed to php scritp then you can use update query. else insert query.